# dart and 3d graphics

Tags: dart

I want to know how is Dart handling or going to handle the graphics part. I know about WebGl but its written in javascript. Dart does have api for it, but would it get something of its own. A 3d library made for it.
and also in just your opinion what is the future of 3d/2d/etc on web.
I know for the fact that websites will become like apps.
I know that the technology that is eventually going to win is has to be open source otherwise a company could just take on a direction of its own. 
I also think that gap between 3d graphics and 2d as is used in websites will narrow down. 
And for this matter flash has the answer(meaning to make something appear you use language A and to just make it 3d you use language B, which is not correct way, as both are graphics.) but it belongs to one company. 
But all other stuff like webgl, opengl,and unity is too complicated and works on very few places.
Mobiles and desktops will have same kind of graphical power, except size...which i am not sure given googles 3d glasses.

I so wanna learn flash...but not. It doesnt need to be this way to make a button you use css and html, but to make it 3d without hacking you go learn 1 tons of libraries and whole javascript.

Comment: Always fun when I'm googling for some information and the first link goes to a closed Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @stesch I think there are too many questions in one, and all of these questions are too vague .. You should better post a new question with a clear question instead of asking for reopen this one.

Comment: @j0k there already was a good answer that helped me. By Colm Sloan on Apr 26. It is gone now. Don't know what happened within the last 14 hours. This question is the first link on Google if you search for "dart language 3d". At it's depressing that it's one of those closed ones. There are too many closed questions on this site. :-(

Comment: i know....i asked it-my first time on this site as dart site keeps saying ask here. Not only my question was blocked but i cant ask more questions here anymore.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer You can still edit your question and rephrase it to be more specific and not so general. One question for now. Then I can help you get a hold of a moderator to reopen the question.

Comment: This question is so old now. Dart has survived more or less. I am not doing AS3 or Dart anymore.